Restarting the SpannerIO's ChangeStream to GCS (TEXT/JSON) Pipeline Got Error
I have setup this pipeline: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided/cloud-spanner-change-streams-to-cloud-storage, by:

hardcode the startTime to certain time (not using timestamp.now()).
specify the metadata table name (so not using the autogenerated one)

The first run was running well. It produced the DataChangeRecord in json format to my gcs bucket.
However, when I stopped it, give it a delay for a while (to simulate when I need to update my pipeline), then started it again, I got this error and the pipeline didn't write any json/text files at all to my gcs.

Error message from worker: generic::invalid_argument: SDK reported a smaller watermarkhold: 2024-09-25T17:32:17.342+00:00 than the computed lower bound: 2024-09-26T01:43:06.072+00:00

At first I thought I need to implement windowing with allowed lateness, so I implemented it by adding the windowing before giving it to TextIO.write
 // apply windowing
      var window = Window.<DataChangeRecord>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(options.getWindowDuration())))
          .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardHours(24))
          .triggering(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()
              .withEarlyFirings(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()
                  .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardMinutes(1)))
              .withLateFirings(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()
                  .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardMinutes(1))))
          .discardingFiredPanes();
  var windowedChangeStreamRecords = dataChangeRecords
      .apply("Windowing", window);

Howver, the issue still persist. Any idea what is wrong with it?
For the context: I am trying to build a simple ingestion process, to ingest Spanner data into GCS (for analytics purpose).

Please check https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided/cloud-spanner-change-streams-to-cloud-storage#optional-parameters:
spannerMetadataTableName : The Spanner change streams connector metadata table name to use. If not provided, a Spanner change streams metadata table is automatically created during pipeline execution. You must provide a value for this parameter when updating an existing pipeline. Otherwise, don't use this parameter.

@XQHu yes, I saw it. I actually already defined the metadata table name. On the second time, i used the same the same metadata table.

The only thing I can do is to use --update the pipeline, so it can resume the ingestion process from the last checkpoint. But I was wondering why draining/canceling can't be done to achieve the same.

This looks like it may be a bug with the spanner connector; it seems to be reporting a watermark which is less than the previously computed watermark, which shouldn't happen - if you're using Beam's spanner io would you mind filing a bug here https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/new?assignees=octocat&labels=bug%2Cawaiting+triage&projects=&template=bug.yml&title=%5BBug%5D%3A+
